# Are we going to [murder] [education]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

Both [education](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) and [murder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder) have > 5 questions, no wiki excerpt, and a poor "tag score".

Should we give them wikis and define a proper use for them, or burninate them?

---

Apparently it was decided to burninate murder. Status completed!

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76885/19561 is the only question on which [tag:education] seems justified. What should we do with that?

Answer (score 14):

I'm not running for mod, so I'll help you out with the more controversial solution:

**Burn both tags.**

Within the context of this Stack, it makes no sense to be an expert in [murder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder) or [education](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education). They are too broad and to general to be of help for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification). These tags are meta-tags that should be deleted.

Comment: [tag:murder] is dead.

Comment: Arqade also had a [murder] tag, but it was [removed for the greater good](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2190/28182)

Answer (score 5):

[education](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) to me looks middle-of-the-road enough that it's not going anywhere soon. It's one of the tags in the "other aspects of a question" category I'm not a fan of, but also not aggressively against. But the questions mostly seem to be about the education system in a fictional work, so that's fine. And that is a topic that people could genuinely be knowledgable about.

I would say that we need to:

- Give it a tag wiki and excerpt (were you volunteering? :) )
- Review the questions tagged with it to make sure it belongs.

  - Bad Use: "What is this story that took place in a school?"
  - Proper Use: "How do OWLs in *Harry Potter* work?"

[murder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder) is more sketchy to me. Only 2 of them seem to be about the concept of murder, the other 4 are about a story where a murder happened to take place. I'd say *at least* remove it from 4 of those 6 questions, and I'm very skeptical about the *Harry Potter* one. That only leaves one question I think it "about [murder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)". I think we all know that *I* recommend there :)

Comment: Is it not better to remove those tags?

Comment: Yeah I can understand.